# Looping through data array

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a narrowcasting solution for our local football club. On one of the pages I'd like to loop through the teams without reloading. Team data is fetched with data attributes. It looks like this:

```
$teamcode = 'seniors1';
$poulecode = 'A';
$teamdata = '
<div id="teamcontainer">
<div data-param-poulecode="'.$poulecode.'"></div>
<div data-param-teamcode="'.$teamcode.'"></div>
</div>
';
echo $teamdata
```

There are multiple teams and multiple poules. Is there a way to loop through an array of teamdata, refreshing the teamcontainer every 10 seconds with new team variables, without reloading the page?

Comment: Ids have to be unique

Comment: As I understand, the loop will be in the server, not in the client. Right? About the refresh, if you want to fetch data **from the server** use [`ajax`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) (Strongly recommend of using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this. If you don't have many items, so return them once from the server and manipulate it in the client using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `data-param-attributes` as arrays of the data using php. Then use jquery to iterate the data and change values. Here's an example:

```
<?php
// Save codes as array
$teamcode = ['seniors1','seniors2'];
$poulecode = ['A','B'];
$teams = json_encode($teamcode);
$poules = json_encode($poulecode);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type= "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="teamcontainer">
        <!--pass variables into data-param attribute-->
        <div id="teams" data-param-teamcode='<?php echo $teams; ?>'></div>
        <div id="poules" data-param-poulecode='<?php echo $poules; ?>'></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var teams = $("#teams").data("paramTeamcode"), poules = $("#poules").data("paramPoulecode");
        var activeTeamIndex = 0, activePouleIndex = 0;

        // Switch teams and poles
        var switchTeams = function(activeIndex){
            $("#teams").text(teams[activeIndex]);
        };
        var switchPoules = function(activeIndex){
            $("#poules").text(poules[activeIndex]);
        };

        // Show the first teams and poules
        switchTeams(0);
        switchPoules(0);

        // Switch teams and poles every 10 seconds
        setInterval(function(){
            // Reset indexes if they exceed array length
            if (activePouleIndex > poules.length)
                activePouleIndex = 0;
            if (activeTeamIndex > teams.length)
                activeTeamIndex = 0;
            switchTeams(activeTeamIndex++);
            switchPoules(activePouleIndex++);
        },10000);
    });
</script>
</html>
```